# if else statement in JS jumps in else statement after if statement is executed

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this if - else statement:

```
if (typeof (answers.QUEST122) === 'undefined') {
                    answers.QUEST122 = '00';
                }
else {
       $scope.answers.QUEST122 = answers.QUEST122.substr(answers.QUEST122.length - 2);
     }
```

For some reason,  when the value is undefined, and answers.QUEST122 is set to '00', the else statement is executed as well, although there is no reason why it would be executed, since the value is undefined.

Is there anything wrong in this if-else statement?

Comment: Does the correct thing here: http://jsfiddle.net/hzeq37ov/  The else will not run. Are you sure this isn't being called again after it sets the value to "00"?

Comment: Thanks @Brian, good advice. Normally when I edit, a deprecated tag will be auto-replaced with its modern equivalent, but I am not well versed in tag editing. Do we (and can we) set that up for the old tag in this case?

Comment: Alright @Brian, thank you. I will try to keep an eye on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working just as expected

```
var answers = {
  "QUEST122": undefined
};

if (typeof answers.QUEST122 === 'undefined') {
  answers.QUEST122 = '00';
} else {
  console.log('hi');
}

// => "00"
```

Paste that into your browser's console and you'll see that it never runs the else block. I think your issue stems from something else. Seeing that you're using Angular, I'd check your logic to see if $scope.QUEST112 is set anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Here works well, so try to use like this

```
typeof (answers.QUEST122) == 'undefined' ? answers.QUEST122 = '00' : $scope.answers.QUEST122 = answers.QUEST122.substr(answers.QUEST122.length - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to look into the object value(CHECK THE ).Nothing wrong with the if-else statement.